# C# FirebirdClient: Can't execute INSERT statement

Tags: c#, insert, firebird

I'm running into a bit of trouble on inserting a row inside a table with FirebirdClient.

This is the table schema

```
FILA     INTEGER Nullable
NUMERO   INTEGER Nullable
STATO    VARCHAR(1) Nullable
UTENTE   VARCHAR(10) Nullable
WEBSYNC  VARCHAR(1) Nullable
```

I need only first two columns to be filled.

This is my code

```
connection.Open();

FbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

FbCommand command = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO TABIMPEG (FILA, NUMERO) VALUES(@row, @number)", connection, transaction);
command.Parameters.Add("@row", row);
command.Parameters.Add("@number", number);

int ok = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();

if (ok != 0) 
    return true;

return false;
```

`Command.ExecuteNonQuery` always returns one row, so the table should be updated. But it's not, in my case.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you explicitly start a transaction, then you also need to commit it before closing the connection, otherwise it'll be rolled back.

Either remove the explicit transaction, or commit it, for example:

```
int ok;
using(FbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    FbCommand command = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO TABIMPEG (FILA, NUMERO) VALUES(@row, @number)", connection, transaction);
    command.Parameters.Add("@row", row);
    command.Parameters.Add("@number", number);

    ok = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    transaction.Commit();
}
// ... rest of your code
```

Comment: YES! I was not committing the transaction. To be precise, the function to call is 'transaction.Commit();'